# local js file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay I have a js file in htdocs and when I include it in my php page it doesn't work however when I load it from online it works I don't know what is wrong with it. 
I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> test</title>
</head>
```

I am putting the js file at the bottom of the page and this doesn't work,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/boostrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wpts_slider_multiple.js"></script>
```

This works,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqueryslidershock.com/wp-content/plugins/tsslider/js/boostrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqueryslidershock.com/wp-content/plugins/tsslider/js/wpts_slider_multiple.js"></script>
```

Comment: whichever browser your opening , just try checking in the JS/web console for errors.It will tell what exactly your problem is .For chrome its F12 to bring up the console

Comment: Check in console and tell us what error you got there

Comment: @MevinBabu I am using Firefox.

Comment: I see  ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined @ http://localhost/js/cloudzoom.js:5. Basically this is another file I don't know if it has something to do with this prob.

Comment: if you include `JQuery` file it must be above all js files
Best place for JQuery file is in head section

Comment: ctrl+shift+k will bring up the web console in firefox

Answer (score 2):

try this: `src="/js/boostrap.js">` instead of `src="js/boostrap.js">`

the `/` is your root path

you can use this absolute path `/js/boostrap.js` in php, js, css files, and it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/boostrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/wpts_slider_multiple.js"></script>
```

Comment: this does not work. I even tried `../`. It used to work before I just don't know what went wrong.

Comment: so you can use `/subfolder/jsfile.js`

Comment: `/` in many servers means your server path, like `http://localhost` or `http://example.com`

Comment: oh but I have a js folder in root directory of localhost. All the js files are inside that folder

Comment: so `/js/` should be work! in php you can use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` for get root path..

Answer (score 0):

try giving the paths like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/boostrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/wpts_slider_multiple.js"></script>

src='/js/boostrap.js'
```

Assuming your root is `http://localhost` then the above link should always resolve to `http://localhost/ProjectName/js/boostrap.js` whether it's called from 
    `http://localhost/ProjectName/index.php` or `http://localhost/ProjectName/subdir/index.php`

Make sure the js files are present within your folder structures

Always try to give relative paths to your files so that they can be easily found.

Comment: htdocs/js/ then all the js files are in here. No other subfolder inside js folder.

Comment: `~` it's for asp.net not php

Answer (score 0):

You should give `full path` of your `jquery files` like

```
http://example.com/js/boostrap.js
```

**Code**

```
<script src="http://example.com/js/boostrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/js/wpts_slider_multiple.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Lmxc If you are working locally then use `http://127.0.0.1/folder-name/js/` and you should know the `actual path` of your `js folder`

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following is happening.

**Incorrect path** - Please check the file paths.

**No Read permission for the JS files** - If you are sure that the path for the local JS files are correct, check their `read` permissions.

**File does not exist** - Simple reason as it states. I believe that it's not the case.

Let me know what you found.